# Extra Spacing in my CSS based navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, spacing

I've been trying to create a navigation menu using css and a series of unordered lists.  I have followed a tutorial which worked very nicely, but have come across a couple of problems when trying to edit it to suit my needs.  There are two main issues that I'm still having trouble with.

1) In each of the sub-nav levels (first and second level) there is an extra space to the right hand side of the created area.  This not only looks silly, but also effects functionality as hovering over that area causes the navigation to close.

2) How can I center the entire navigation?  I've tried using text-align in each of the `<div>` and `<nav>` elements without any luck.

You can view the code as I've written it so far at: http://bootply.com/105634 (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YAxvy/)

Sorry for all the silly colors, I was just trying to see where everything was going.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Put your code on JsFiddle.net

Comment: I know SO likes JSFiddle, but is there anything wrong with using a similar site? For all I can tell, 'bootply' seems to have the same goal in mind as JSF.

Comment: hmm just noticed the sub sub level going through css, your left:122% is too much, you should first reset default padding on li and then rearrange your coordonates .

Comment: @JHuangweb Took me 3 seconds ._. http://jsfiddle.net/YAxvy/ (now get back to his problem please)

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm not the one asking the question ;)

Comment: Is this really the type of support that should be offered is who uses the best web based IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YAxvy/7/ (updated to fix `left` and `padding` issues on sub sub menu)

The problem was that the `.sub-menu ul` had a padding on it (not just on the top). I have removed this.

**Problem 2:**

Instead of using `float:left` you can use `display: inline-block` which displays them side-by-side and allows you to align them any way you like.

```
nav > ul > li {
    // add this line
    display: inline-block;    
}
// remove float:left from nav ul
nav > ul { 
    // and add this one
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

All together now! http://jsfiddle.net/YAxvy/7/

Comment: THis still does not achieve centering

Comment: Your posting jsfiddles with your corrections not properly placed. FYI.

Comment: It looks like you missed the padding for the ul. Make sure to remove the padding-left to 0 so it is properly aligned center. I missed it to at first.

Comment: Hopefully he would be using a proper reset css on all his elements so that this is not a worry of his.

Comment: Basically all his sub-menu problems are solved just by using `padding: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will fix it.

```
            nav ul li {
              display: inline-block;
              vertical-align: center;
              position: relative;
              line-height: 20px;
            }
            nav ul { 
              list-style: none; 
              text-align: center; 
            }

            nav ul {
              list-style: none outside none;
              padding-left: 0;
              text-align: center;
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/YAxvy/6/

Comment: Make sure it's only applying to direct descendants! Use `>`

Comment: I realize this, I am just using the current construct. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I played around with it for a bit and am still not getting exactly what I need.  I think this is because of what Fred mentioned above.  
As it stands now the main nav gets centered, but the sub nav items are also centered and put all onto one line (instead of in a list).

Any help/elaboration would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/bKESx/) *updated*

```
    #container {
        padding: 10px;
        background:olive;
    }
    #content {
        margin:25px;
        padding:10px;
        background:orange;
    }
    #container > nav > ul {
        margin: 0 330px;
    }
    nav {
        background:yellow;
    }
    /* MAIN MENU */
    nav {
        margin: 25px auto;
    }
    /*gap at top*/
    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    /*get rid of bullets*/
    /*adds a proper clear to put content back in the correct place*/
    nav ul:after {
        content:'.';
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        height: 0px;
    }
    nav ul li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-right: -40px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        color: #102601;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 14px 15px 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
        /*ADD OTHER BROWSER TRANSITIONS*/
    }
    /*the icon before the top level links*/
    nav > ul > li > a:before {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #102601;
        /*circle color*/
        color: #e4e4e4;
        /*icon color*/
        width: 1.65em;
        /*circle size*/
        height: 1.65em;
        border-radius: 1.65em;
        /*makes it a circle*/
        line-height: 1.65em;
        /*centers icon vertically in circle*/
        text-align: center;
        /*centers icon horizontally in circle*/
        box-shadow: 0.125em 0.175em 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
        /*adds shaddow to circle*/
        margin-right: 0.75em;
        /*adds some space between icon and text*/
        -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
    /*the hover and active state for the icon*/
    nav > ul > li:hover > a:before, nav > ul li > a.active:before {
        background:#6DA617;
        color:white;
    }
    /* SUB MENU */
    /*triangle before*/
    nav ul li > ul:before {
        content:"";
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 9px 9px 9px;
        border-color: transparent transparent #2C3E50 transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 5px;
        top: -10px;
    }
    nav ul li > ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 14px;
        top: 80%;
        padding-top: 13px;
        background: white;
        z-index: -9999;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
        white-space:nowrap;
        padding-left:0;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 1;
        top: 100%;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li:first-child {
        border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }
    nav ul li > ul {
        border:1px solid black;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li {
        padding: 0;
        width:100%;
        left:-40px;
        /*background:green;*/
    }
    nav ul li > ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 6px 9px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li:hover > a {
        color: #FFF;
        background: pink;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li.active > a {
        color: #FFF;
        background: red;
    }
    /* SUB SUB MENU */
    /*the triangle*/
    nav ul li > ul li > ul:before {
        content:"";
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 9px 9px 9px;
        border-color: transparent transparent #2C3E50 transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: -14px;
        top: 15px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    nav ul li > ul li > ul {
        top: 0;
        left: 90%;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    nav ul li > ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
```